# Java chat,sockets con threads. No puedo conectar más de un cliente

Tags: java, hilos, socket

Estoy haciendo un chat donde el servidor y el cliente se comunican mediante Sockets, yo quiero que el cliente pueda comunicarse con otro cliente, pero no puedo conseguirlo, ayuda por favor?,llevo mucho tiempo intentando conseguirlo y no puedo:(

Código:https://gist.github.com/FillingMussel28/7ffa56503b69f377936b73b8f3dbd7d1

Comment: Por favor coloca solo la parte relevante del código como texto en la pregunta y explica un poco más sobre donde está el problema que te impide avanzar.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a leer cómo incluir un [mcve] en tu pregunta. Un saludo.